# Why the PHP fopen() function is not working with 755 and 775 folder permissions?

Tags: php, logging, permissions, file-permissions, fopen

I am using ACRA (https://github.com/ACRA/acra) for automatically posting my Android crash reports to a report server. I have a PHP script that uses the following lines for writing the log file to the `https://example.com/logs/` folder on my testing server:

```
$FileLog = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/logs/" . $fname;
$HandleLog = fopen($FileLog, 'a');
```

The PHP `fopen()` function is only working correctly for me when the `logs/` folder on my server has these permissions:

```
drwxrwxrwx (777)
```

I already tried `drwxrwxr-x (775)` and `drwxr-xr-x (755)` and the `fopen()` function is not working. It only works when I use `drwxrwxrwx (777)` for the `logs/` folder permissions.

That is weird to me because the PHP script that I am running is on my server, so when I execute `fopen($FileLog, 'a')` from that PHP file on my server, it should work correctly if `https://example.com/logs/` is a folder with `drwxrwxr-x (775)` permissions, since the PHP script that uses `fopen($FileLog, 'a')` is also on the same `https://example.com` server. Do you have any hints about why only 777 permissions are working? I know `drwxrwxrwx (777)` permissions for a web server is a no-no. Thanks.

**UPDATE 1:**

The PHP script that uses `fopen($FileLog, 'a')` is hosted at `https://example.com/loggingscript.php` and it is invoked by the ACRA library (https://github.com/ACRA/acra) from my Android app when it crashes.

Comment: I think `0775` means the user that creates the file has to be in the same group as the web user. Does the web user also create the file or is it a different user?

Comment: @Halcyon My Android app triggers a POST request to `https://example.com/loggingscript.php`. Then `loggingscript.php` is the file that contains `fopen($FileLog, 'a')` and what that tries to do is to create a file in `https://example.com/logs/`, a folder whose permissions I am trying to set at `755` or `775`, not `777`, but it is only working when I use `777` for the permissions of `https://example.com/logs/`. Obviously, I cannot have `777` for the permissions of that directory on a web server that anyone can visit.

Comment: Does the log file already exist? With `775` permissions, only the directory owner or group can create new files.

Comment: Is the web user the owner of the folder? (or in the same group as the owner of the folder?) You can make it the owner by using `chown`

Comment: If the file already exists, it should work with either directory permissions, but the file permissions will control whether you can write to it.

Comment: I'm not sure what point you're trying to make in the paragraph that starts with "That is weird". Of course the file is on the same server, permissions are for access control between different users on the same server.

Comment: @Barmar The log file does not exist. What I want is to create that file, since it does not exist because it should be created when my Android app crashes so that I can save logs about what happened in that file. The directory `owner` and `group` is `root`. But the script is executed by `https://example.com/loggingscript.php`, a file that is also owned by `root`.

Comment: The ownership of the script doesn't matter. Web scripts are run by whatever userid runs the webserver, typically something like `www-user`. So change the owner of the directory to that userid.

Comment: @Halcyon Basic terminology that I am not getting, but what do you mean by `web user`? The owner of `https://example.com/logs/` is `root` and `root` is also the `group` for that folder. Same thing for `https://example.com/loggingscript.php`, `root` is both `owner` and `group`.

Comment: Ok yea, then you need to change it, see Barmar's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory should be owned by the user that runs the webserver. Otherwise, it needs world-write permission so that other users can write to it.

This might be something like `www-data` or `apache`. If you're not sure what this is, see

[Finding out what user Apache is running as?](https://serverfault.com/questions/125865/finding-out-what-user-apache-is-running-as)

Comment: It was `www-data` in my case. See the "UPDATE 2" section of my question. Your solution fixed the problem. Thank you Barmar.

Comment: That's what I was actually thinking of, I just couldn't remember the common username off the top of my head and didn't feel like looking it up myself.

Comment: The full solution should be in an answer, not the question.

Comment: How should I put my `UPDATE 2` in your answer? Do I create another answer myself? I like the extra details that I provided but you are right, it does not seem good to include part of the answer/solution in my question.

Comment: It does not seem fair to choose my own answer as the best answer only because it was more detailed because the real solution was your answer and then I only added details about the specific steps that I followed. Nonetheless, you can let me know what the best practice is in terms of choosing a best answer. I feel that it is fair to leave your answer as the best one, since it is clearly the solution.

Answer (score 1):

While normally Barmar gives very good advice here, on this occasion, I disagree with "The directory should be owned by the user that runs the webserver".

Each digit in the octal permission, and each of "rwx" in the permissions string is associated with the user, the group and any other uid (where the user and group are the attributes on the file). If your PHP script should write logs then it needs permission to execute and write to the directory as any of the user, the group or other. While generally the webserver uid should be the least privileged account on a dedicated webserver host (and therefore granted access via "other") this is not always the case. If, for example, there is also an email MTA on the host, then a better solution might be 770 with the webserver granted access via the group ownership. Setting the webserver uid as the owner of a directory should always be an automatic red flag.

The permissions model you put in place should reflect all access to the files, enabling *all* the relevant parties to access the file (web developers, backup software, log rotation service accounts...) it should also limit access from anyone not explicitly intended to have access. The OP has told us nothing about the user/group associated with the directory / whether this is changeable / whom needs what access).

> I know drwxrwxrwx (777) permissions for a web server is a no-no

Not necessarily - this should **never** be a default, but sometimes it is the right configuration for content intended to be writeable by the webserver uid. The reason people get excited about this is that it is often seen as a quick fix by people having problem with permissions whom should not be providing PHP with write access to the content.

There is also a **massive** security vulnerability being exposed here (in the absence of other mitigations not mentioned). The main reason for restricting where PHP can write is to prevent injection of code by end users. In order to effect an exploit the attacker must also have a way of invoking the code they have placed on your server. Typically logs contain user supplied data - hence allowing PHP to write the data enables the first stage of an attack. If the data is written within the document root, then it is directly addressable via URL from a browser.

That the OP changed the permissions to 755 did nothing to mitigate this attack and has created a situation where only the PHP code and root user can remove the log files after they have been created.

Comment: I don't understand your disagreement. If the only use of this directory is for log files from the webserver, then why shouldn't it be owned by that user? Giving it `777` permissions allows other users to create or remove files when they shouldn't. If the directory is used by multiple users it would justify creating a group for all of them, but still not world-write.

Comment: I agree with your point that log files probably don't belong in document root, although `.htaccess` can be used to prevent access from a browser. It also won't be executable unless it has an extension like `.php` (and even if it does, it probably won't have PHP syntax since the script is generating the contents).

Comment: Only root can change the uid of a file - so either the OP has to have root access or the webserver uid created the directory (implying it is within a directory the uid can write to).

Comment: There is no *functional* difference between the write access as user, or group or other, but implementing via something other than user guarantees alternate control access, and differentiates the artefact from something created by design for a purpose from indicators of a compromise (yes, if an attacker gets root access they can assign any user they like to a file, but privilege escalation is a secondary step to an initial compromise).

Comment: The website administrator usually has root access so they can install files and scripts.

Comment: website administrator != root

Comment: It usually requires root access, since you have to install files into directories owned by www-data, or change files to be owned by that user. Maybe if you use a management system like cpanel they don't need full sudo access, though.

Answer (score 0):

Barmar's answer was the solution. But to document exactly what I did, I am writing my detailed steps below.

Running `# ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'` revealed that the user running the web server was `www-data`:

```
# ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'
www-data  3735  0.0  2.6 273160 12996 ?        S    06:25   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  3736  0.0  2.6 273148 12892 ?        S    06:25   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  3738  0.0  2.6 273216 13092 ?        S    06:25   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  7163  0.0  2.6 273180 12888 ?        S    12:56   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  7165  0.0  2.6 273176 13000 ?        S    12:56   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  8209  0.0  2.6 273200 13032 ?        S    14:26   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  8211  0.0  2.6 273128 12904 ?        S    14:26   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  8219  0.0  2.6 273128 12896 ?        S    14:26   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  8221  0.0  3.3 273192 16412 ?        S    14:26   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  8235  0.0  2.6 273196 13008 ?        S    14:26   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root     12976  0.0  0.2  13136  1048 pts/0    S+   22:09   0:00 grep -E --color=auto (apache|httpd)
root     29850  0.0  4.7 268240 23488 ?        Ss   Aug07   0:10 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

I changed the ownership of that folder from `root` to `www-data`:

```
# chown www-data logs/
# chgrp www-data logs/
```

Now everything works correctly while I have `755` as the permissions of my `logs` folder.